# Ubuntu/Gnome: System Menu on all Monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, menu, globalmenu

so I am using Multi Monitors to have the menus on all monitors, and currently am getting partial success.

My goal is having the EXACT same menu at the top at all times: Activities (Done), App Menu (I could only get it on the monitor where the app is open, would like that it to be on both but ok), Date&Time (Done), language (would be nice, not very important), and most importantly: the system menu (the one on the right).

Any idea how I could do that? Am I missing something within Multi Monitors?